# VC++ 20?? Redistributable installer hangs on "Initializing..."

Tags: windows-8, installation, visual-c++, redistributable

I'm trying to get the MS Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable installed on my machine. A game requires it. I'm running Windows 8.1. I tried a few different redist versions earlier today, and each worked. I've uninstalled/repaired/and installed with a few different versions. It just turns out that they were incompatible versions.

Anyways, I tried the installing the most recent (2015), but ended up closing the installer while it was in the middle of doing something. Windows now thinks that the MS VC++ 2015 Redist. package is installed, but I know it's not, because I closed it out mid-install.

Now any time I run any version of the installer, it just sits there with this text over the progress bar: "Processing:    Initializing..."

I can't uninstall, I can't repair, and I can't run any other version of the installer. It just hangs there, and there's no way around it. I've tried using alternative 3rd-party app uninstallers, and they all just bring up the redist installation program. I ended up finding a package cache directory for it with a long hash for the filename, and I deleted its contents to no avail. I've rebooted dozens of times, and killed numerous processes that seem attached to the installer.

Nothing is working and I'm at my wits end. Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround for it without formatting? Are there some cached files I can delete or registry keys/values I can clear?

Comment: Check the installation logs. Make sure you have enough disk space

Comment: I have over 1.5 terabytes of free disk space. Where could I find the installation logs for this package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VC++ 2008 redistributable install error: Access is denied](http://superuser.com/questions/1025364/vc-2008-redistributable-install-error-access-is-denied)