# VC++ 2008 redistributable install error: Access is denied

Tags: installation, visual-c++, redistributable

Installing OpenOffice 4.1.2 raises the error 1935. (Visual C++ 2008 redistributable failed to install). However, the installation completes and OpenOffice works normally.

Nonetheless, I decided to investigate launching vcredist_x86.exe manually. Installation log reports these lines:

> MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:34:33:070]: Executing op: SetTargetFolder(Folder=c:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_51ca66a2bbe76806)
>   MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:34:33:070]: Executing op: SetSourceFolder(Folder=1\Windows\winsxs\ulATLx86)
>   MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:34:33:070]: Executing op: AssemblyCopy(SourceName=ax86.dll|atl90.dll,SourceCabKey=ul_atl90.dll.30729.4148.Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.QFE,DestName=atl90.dll,Attributes=0,FileSize=159032,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,ElevateFlags=4,,,,ComponentId={A75F2217-AD54-3EA6-AE14-F255F8660531},,,,AssemblyMode=0,)
>   MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:34:33:071]: Assembly Error:Access is denied.
>
> MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:34:33:071]: Note: 1: 1935 2: {A75F2217-AD54-3EA6-AE14-F255F8660531} 3: 0x80070005 4: IAssemblyCache 5: CreateAssemblyCacheItem 6: Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version="9.0.30729.4148",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32" 
>   MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:34:33:071]: Assembly Error (sxs): Please look into Component Based Servicing Log located at %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log to get more diagnostic information.
>   MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:39:03:761]: Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148 -- Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version="9.0.30729.4148",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070005. assembly interface: IAssemblyCache, function: CreateAssemblyCacheItem, component: {A75F2217-AD54-3EA6-AE14-F255F8660531}
>
> Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version="9.0.30729.4148",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070005. assembly interface: IAssemblyCache, function: CreateAssemblyCacheItem, component: {A75F2217-AD54-3EA6-AE14-F255F8660531}
>   MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:39:03:776]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
>   MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:39:03:777]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
>   MSI (s) (80:E0) [18:39:03:777]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
>   Action ended 18:39:03: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log does not contain any helpful information. I don't want to do a major system reinstallation or cleanup as many articles advise, I want to find the specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lots of googling, I found a mention of **C:\Windows\WinSxS\InstallTemp** [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/373931-error-1935-installing-ms-visual-c-x64-2008-others-2.html). I could not find a mention of **InstallTemp** in installation logs, but it turned out to be the culprit: neither the logged-in-user nor Administrator had modify access to the folder (why?). I verified on another (normal) computer that the user *can* create sub-folders in it.

So, I added **Modify** rights to Administrators in the folder's properties Security tab. After that, redistributable installation worked.

Comment: The issue is mentioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/07/installation-of-vc-2005-2008-redistributables-fail-with-0x80070005-assembly-error-access-is-denied-issue.aspx 

Nnormally MSIExec runs installers under the SYSTEM account which has only read/list rights on the WinSxS folder but full rights on WinSxS\InstallerTemp. It looks like you overwrote the security descriptor on WinSxS\InstallerTemp with the one on WinSxS.